# Why Not Hybrid Out-Of-Order, Massively Parallel?

Tags: cpu, multicore, cpu-architecture, parallel-processing

It seems in vogue to predict that superscalar out-of-order CPUs are going the way of the dodo and will be replaced by huge amounts of simple, scalar, in-order cores.  This doesn't seem to be happening in practice because, even if the problem of parallelizing software were solved tomorrow, there's still tons of legacy software out there.  Besides, parallelizing software is not a trivial problem.

I understand that GPGPU is a hybrid model, where the CPU is designed for single-thread performance and the graphics card for parallelism, but it's an ugly one.  The programmer needs to explicitly rewrite code to run on the graphics card, and to the best of my understanding expressing parallelism efficiently for a graphics card is much harder than expressing it efficiently for a multicore general-purpose CPU.

What's wrong with a hybrid model where every PC comes with one or two "expensive" superscalar out-of-order cores and 32 or 64 "cheap" cores, but with the same instruction set as the expensive cores and possibly on the same piece of silicon?  The operating system would be aware of this asymmetry and would schedule the out-of-order cores first and with the highest priority threads.  This prioritization might even be explicitly exposed to the programmer via the OS API, but the programmer wouldn't be forced to care about the distinction unless he/she wanted to control the details of the scheduling.

Edit:  If the vote to close is because this supposedly isn't programming related, here's a rebuttal:  I think it is programming-related because I want to hear programmers' perspective on why such a model is a good or bad idea and whether they would want to program to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W00t, what a great question =D

In a glance, I can see two problems. I advice you that for now on I'll be considering a CPU bounded parallel application when exposing my arguments.

The first one is the control overhead imposed to the operating system. Remember, the OS is responsible for dispatching the processes to the CPU they will run on. Moreover, the OS needs to control the concurrent access to the data structures that holds this information. Thus, you got the first bottleneck of having the OS abstracting the schedule of tasks. This is already a drawback.

The following is a nice experiment. Try to write an application that makes a lot of use of the CPU. Then, with some other application, like atsar, get the statics of user and system time. Now, vary the number of concurrent threads and look to what happens to the system time. Plotting data may help to figure the growth of (not so =) useless processing.

Second, as you add cores to your system, you also need a more powerful bus. CPU cores need to exchange data with the memory so a computation may be done. Thus, with more cores, you'll have more concurrent access to the bus. Someone may argue that a system with more than one bus can be designed. Yes, indeed, such a system may be designed. However, extra mechanisms must be in place to keep the integrity of the data used by the cores. Some mechanism do exist at cache-level, however they are very very expensive to be deployed in the primary memory-level.

Keep in mind that every time a thread changes some data in the memory, this change must be propagated to others threads when they access this data, an action that is usual in parallel applications (mainly in numerical ones).

Nevertheless, I do agree with your position that the current models are ugly. And yes, nowadays is much more difficult to express parallelism in GPGPU programming models as the programmer is totally responsible for moving bits around. I anxiously hope for more succinct, high-level and standardized abstraction for many-core and GPGPU application development.

Answer (score 2):

@aikigaeshi thanks for mentioning my paper. I am Yale Patt's student and actually the first author of the paper titled accelerating critical sections. We came up with the idea after a lot of studies. In fact, I recently gave a major talk at an industry conference about this. Here is my take after studying it for several years:

@dsimcha , the question  should be split into two parts for a good analysis.

1. Do we need need the ability to run some code faster than the rest? This question then leads to a simpler question: is some code more critical than the rest. I defined a critical code as any code for which threads content. When a thread contends for a pice of code to finish execution, the code the thread is waiting for clearly becomes more critical because speeding up that code not only speeds up the thread executing the code currently but also speeds up the thread waiting for the current thread to finish the execution. Single-threaded kernels is a great examples where all threads wait for a single thread to finish. Critical sections is another example where all threads wanting to enter the critical section must wait for any previous thread to finish the critical section. Running such critical code faster is clearly a good idea because when a code is being contended-for, it inherently becomes more performance-critical.  There are other scenarios like reductions, load imbalance, loaner thread problems, that can lead to critical code and executing this code faster can help. So I strongly conclude that there is need for what I call performance asymmetry.
2. How can we provide provide performance asymmetry? Having big and small cores together in the same system is one way of providing this asymmetry. While this is the architecture I explored, a lot of research should be done in exploring other ways to provide asymmetry. Frequency scaling, prioritizing memory requests from the critical threads, giving more resources to the critical thread, are all possible ways of providing asymmetry. Coming back to big and small core architecture: My research found it to be feasible in most cases as the overhead of migrating the tasks to the big core was offset by the benefit you obtained from accelerating the critical code. I would skip the details but there are some very interesting trade-offs. I encourage you to read my papers or my PhD thesis for the detail.

I also want to point out a few major facts. 
-I was able to leverage this asymmetric chip (ACMP) without modifying the software programs so thats kind of proof that it will not increase the work for application programmers
-I did not find the OS work to be challenging. I implemented a run-time all by myself in a couple of weeks which worked great for my studies. I understand that there is his fear in the Os community to change OSes and I appreciate the value of engineering resources, however, I disagree that OS changes should be a limiter. Its problems that will be overcome with time.

-After year of writing parallel programs, studying existing programs, studying processor designs, and working at major companies, I am actually convinced that the ACMP actually will help the programmers. In the current model, programmers write a parallel program and then identify the serial bottleneck and then hammer on it until its parallelized and then move on to the next bottleneck. Im general, bottlenecks become harder and harder to tackle and diminishing returns kicks in. If the hardware provided some ability to run the bottleneck faster --magically-- then the programmers would not have to waste so much time to get parallel performance. They could parallelize the easier-to-parallelize code and leave the rest on hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Your post reads more like a hypothesis than an enquiry.  This topic is known as *heterogeneous architectures* and is currently a lively research area.  You can find interesting workshops and keynotes on hetero strategies at industry conferences.

http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=heterogeneous+architectures&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=on

> What's wrong with a hybrid model where
>   every PC comes with one or two
>   "expensive" superscalar out-of-order
>   cores and 32 or 64 "cheap" cores, but
>   with the same instruction set as the
>   expensive cores and possibly on the
>   same piece of silicon?

There's nothing "wrong" with it, but there are numerous practical difficulties.  For example, you mention scheduling by thread priority, but this is only one of many metrics needed to make smart scheduling decisions.  What if your highest priority thread is a data streaming app that makes very poor use of the big core caches?  Would your net system performance increase to schedule this streaming app on a small core?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea sounds much like AMD's plans for Fusion. AMD is integrating a GPU onto the CPU. Right now, this is for their low-power slower designs intended to replace Intel's Atom but they are moving it up into laptop chips.

I believe the rumors are pretty reliable that AMD's Bulldozer design for server chips will be using Fusion in a couple of years, possibly entirely replacing the Bulldozer floating point units.

These GPU units are not using the same instruction set, but consider that with the GPU built into the CPU the compiler itself is free to use it just as if it was any other type of MMX/SSE vector instruction type.

A possible example is a loop doing math on a C++ vector of floating point numbers. The compiler, with optimizations set to AMD-Whatever, could write machine code to pin the vector memory, invoke a GPU program and wait for the results.

This is only a bit more complicated than what the auto-vectorize optimizations for SSE do already: they load the data into a XMM register, do the operation and split the data back out of the register.

Comment: @dsimcha: It will work well *if* the programmer uses a pattern that matches what the compiler is looking for. In other words, they may as well have used the SSE intrinsics. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the big architecture guys would actually agree with you in that heterogenous architectures show a lot of promise. I saw a talk by [Yale Patt](http://hps.ece.utexas.edu/media/talks/UPCRC-2010-04-30yp.asf) the other day in which he took this position, predicting that the next generation of successful architectures would consist of a few large fast cores supplemented with a lot of smaller cores. One group used this idea to actually mitigate the overheads of concurrency by providing a bigger core to which threads executing in [critical sections](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~omutlu/pub/acs_asplos09.pdf) could be migrated.